# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion

This question makes perfect sense, [**How do I select distinct json columns?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/155828/2639) It's not my question, but it's totally valid. I even answered it.

Comment: Seeing as you seem to have understood the question well enough to get the tick, Are you able to edit it for clarity? I still find the question very unclear.

Comment: As a suggestion; try adding your query that is producing the duplication. If you are trying to get unique records you might just need to create a transition table to grab the unique values you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I was one of the people who voted to close the question. I voted to close because it wasn't clear to me what the user's goal was. [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter) said it quite well [in his comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155828/how-do-i-select-distinct-json-columns#comment297818_155828):

> Do you just want coordinates or whole rows with distinct coordinates? In the later case you need to define which row from a set of peers.  Also, please always provide table definition and Postgres version.

That comment was posted two days ago and the OP didn't clarify their question. When a poster is unresponsive and the question is unclear then it feels like closing is an appropriate move.

---

Amazingly right as I posted this the OP edited their post. Hopefully the OP clarifies the question to a point we can reopen it.

Comment: The lack of response from the OP was my reason to kick off the closing process too. I hesitated at first because there aren't many questions of that kind on the site and this one could make a valuable contribution – if it was clear enough.

Comment: @AndriyM and it seemed to be helpful since the OP just edited the question. Hopefully they edit it to address Erwin's comment instead of just add test data like they've done so far.